# Why npm installs my github repo multiple times and does not do it only once at the top of the tree?

Tags: npm

I have a couple of private github repos, and a simplified dependency tree looks something like this.

```
A
+-B
| +-D
| +-lodash
|
+-C
| +-D
| +-lodash
|
+-D
+-lodash
```

My private github repo D is installed by npm as many times as it is used and lodash is installed only once in the top of the tree. 
It is the same version of D and same version of lodash in every package.

So why D is treated differently? 
Is there a way to make npm treat D the same way it treats lodash?

Comment: Are the versions of `D`, used by `B` and `C` different or hardcoded? If you set `*` (which is considered a bad practice) as dependency then npm will not install it multiple times, but all modules will use the that is  in `A`

Comment: It looks like this in every package.json `"D": "github:user/repo_name"`

Comment: Yeah, I guess this a bug in npm: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3081

Comment: this is because npm uses the relative path to install modules and in yur case every time path is different

Answer (score 0):

As [Vasil Dininski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182899/vasil-dininski) mentioned, this is a [npm bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3081). 
For now a possible workaround is to use [force-dedupe-git-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/force-dedupe-git-modules)